# Django: "ZeroToOneField" DoesNotExist Error

Tags: django, model, one-to-one

I'm trying to determine the best way to make a "zero-to-one" relationship between two models.  For example, a model named Post can have zero or one related model instances of a Model called PostExtra.  I'd like the reverse to be true as well.

```
from django.db import models

class PostExtra(models.Model):

    author = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)  

    """
    Assigned a property to prevent DoesNotExist error when calling 
    self.post, but property does not override self.post properly 
    for some reason. 
    """ 
    def _get_post(self):
        return_value=None
        try:
            return_value = self.post
        except:
            pass
        return return_value

    def _set_post(self, post):
        self.post = post

    post = property(_get_post, _set_post)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.author)

class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    text = models.TextField()
    extra = models.OneToOneField('a.PostExtra', blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.title)
```

Here, I can create a Post()

```
>>> p = Post(title="test 1", text="test text")
>>> p.save()
>>> p.extra    # this returns None as it should
```

As above, since I made Post.extra a OneToOneField with blank=True/null=True, p.extra will return Null if no PostExtra is assigned.  However, if I do the reverse and try to access PostExtra.post, I get a DoesNotExist error.

```
>>> pe = PostExtra(author='John Doe')
>>> pe.save()
>>> pe.post 
...
DoesNotExist: Post matching query does not exist.
```

I tried assigning a property on PostExtra to override the PostExtra.post using a property, but I still get the error.  Has anyone found a way to get OneToOneFields to not throw an exception (and return Null) when trying to access a non-existent related element?

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Your try/except doesn't catch the error, or was that something you added in later?  Calling `self.post` from within `_get_post()` seems like it would recurse anyway.

Comment: Thanks Jack M.  Since doing "except:" by itself catches any exception, shouldn't it also catch a DoesNotExist exception?

Comment: The more important bit was that had your code worked, you would have been recursing into it over and over again as `PostExtra.post` (which was redirected to `_get_post()`), called `PostExtra.post`, which would call `PostExtra.post`, etc, until Python barfs all over your brand new shoes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to specify a different [`related_name` on your relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) in order to make this type of code work.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
class PostExtra(models.Model):
    pass ## Brevity.
    def _get_post(self):
        return_value=None
        try:
            return_value = self._post
        except ObjectDoesNotExist: ## Be explicit if you can.
            pass
        return return_value
    def _set_post(self, post):
        self._post = post
    post = property(_get_post, _set_post)

class Post(models.Model):
    pass ## Brevity.
    extra = models.OneToOneField('a.PostExtra', blank=True,
                      null=True, related_name='_post')
```

You can then access the post in a few different ways:

```
>>> pe = PostExtra(author='John Doe')
>>> pe.save()
>>> pe.post
None
>>> pe._post
DoesNotExist: Post matching query does not exist.
```

**Ninja Edit:**
The question may be raised, "Why do I have to do it this way?".  The answer is because when the Django model classes set up your `PostExtra` object, it is creating `PostExtra.post` as a reference back to `Post`.  I'm not familiar with the code itself, but I doubt it checks to make sure the coast is clear before doing the assignment, since the programmer told it to make that relation.  As a result, you have to specify a non-conflicting property for Django's model classes to use, thus the `related_name` argument.

Comment: Thanks again. That seems to work  Hiding the related name as a private variable will at least help keep it from being called.